# connected users data in squid

Tags: linux, squid

for internet access, i config squid to authenticate users with win active directory.

when a user enter username and pass check with AC users. is a way to know what user from what ip connected?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to see information like "John Doe is currently authenticated from 192.168.1.105" but you can fetch the list of currently connected client IPs from Squid Cache Manager CGI (cachemgr.cgi) or via SNMP using SQUID.MIB and cacheClientTable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Squid's `access.log`. It will report both the client IP address and the user name, if the user is authenticated.

Comment: no, i say seassion details for connected users. for example users that close web browser or expire his seassion, logs that

Comment: How could the proxy server know the user closed its browser? That's simply not possible, the HTTP protocol doesn't specify that this information should be sent by the browser to the web server (or proxy).

Comment: i mean that close session, when a user close his browser and open that again must enter user-name and pass again

Comment: There's no authentication session on the proxy, the browser simply remebers your credentials after you enter them for the first time. Eveyr HTTP request is authenticated on its own, as HTTP is a connectionless protocol.

Comment: OK, that authentication details where store?

Comment: They're not stored anywhere on the proxy server, they are stored on the client browser.